# CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS when trying to write from image to image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I decided to try to start learning OpenCL. I spent a lot of time compiling and the like, and finally I have a Qt project with OpenCV embedded and OpenCL working. The information on the internet about the next steps is kinds scarce though. Using other stackoverflow posts, I botched together this kernel, which should swap image color channels.

This is my kernel:

```
__kernel void shift(                                        
   read_only image2d_t input,                               
   float shift_x,                                           
   float shift_y,                                           
   write_only image2d_t output,                             
   int dst_step, int dst_offset, int dst_rows, int dst_cols)
{                                                           
   int2 coord = (get_global_id(1), get_global_id(0));       
   uint4 pixel = read_imageui(input, samplerLN, coord);     
   // create pixel with swapped channels                    
   uint4 pixel2;                                            
   pixel2.s0 = pixel.s1;                                    
   pixel2.s1 = pixel.s2;                                    
   pixel2.s2 = pixel.s0;                                    
   write_imageui(output, coord, pixel2);                    
}
```

And this is how I try to run it:

```
  //! run gpu operation
  cv::ocl::Device(context.device(0));

  cv::Mat imageOpenCL = cv::imread("D:\\images\\20200424_162602.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  imageOpenCL.convertTo(imageOpenCL, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255);
  cv::UMat umat_src = imageOpenCL.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);
  cv::UMat umat_dst(imageOpenCL.size(), CV_32F, cv::ACCESS_WRITE, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);

  cv::ocl::ProgramSource program(source);


  cv::ocl::Image2D imageCL(umat_src);
  cv::ocl::Image2D imageCLOut(umat_dst);
  float shift_x = 100.5;
  float shift_y = -50.0;
  cv::ocl::Kernel kernel("shift", program);
  kernel.args(imageCL, shift_x, shift_y, imageCLOut);

  size_t globalThreads[3] = { (size_t)imageOpenCL.cols, (size_t)imageOpenCL.rows, 1 };
  //size_t localThreads[3] = { 16, 16, 1 };
  bool success = kernel.run(3, globalThreads, NULL, true);
  if (!success){
      std::cout << "Failed running the kernel..." << std::endl;
      return;
  }

  // Download the dst data from the device (?)
  cv::Mat mat_dst = umat_dst.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);

  cv::imshow("src", imageOpenCL);
  cv::imshow("dst", mat_dst);
```

I'm probably copying the data wrong, but I'm not sure what to do. I also tried different types instead of `CV_32F` for the image, such as `CV_8U` and `CV_8UC3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel has 8 arguments; you are only setting 4 of them. Hence, the CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS error. It does not appear you are using the last 4 arguments in the kernel; this fix seems to be to remove them from the kernel argument list.